# How to solve VisibleDeprecation WARNING

Tags: python, class, numpy, scikit-learn, label

I am using famous iris dataset and want to apply a supervised learning classifier. My problem is i want to apply the classifier on the two column features. And i want to have only two classes instead of three classes. The original dataset has 3 classes and 4 features per sample. When i want to select only two features and remove one class, i am getting the warning as follows:

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 150 but corresponding boolean dimension is 100
```

How i can remove this warning?

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm, datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
X, y = X[y != 2], y[y != 2]
X = iris.data[:, [2, 3]]
X, y = X[y != 2], y[y != 2]
X.shape
```

Answer (score 1):

You failed to reset y although you reset X:

```
X = iris.data[:, [2, 3]]
```

After this line `X` is now 150 entries long while y is still 100. You then index using the boolean array of `y != 2` which is 100 elements long, thus the error. Do the following to fix this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm, datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
X, y = X[y != 2], y[y != 2]
X = iris.data[:, [2, 3]]
y = iris.target
X, y = X[y != 2], y[y != 2]
X.shape
```